# Boolean indexing in pandas combining a variable number of columns

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a (pythonic) way to loop over columns in dataframe for boolean-indexing in pandas ?

I'm not sure you can do this using list comprehension...

The only way I've found would be :

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
    ["a", "b", "c"],
    ["d", "e", "f"],
    ["g", "h", "i"],
    ], 
    columns=["A", "B", "C"],
    )

my_filter = {
    "A":{"a", "g"},
    "B":{"e"},
    }
    
series = [
        df[f].isin(v)==True for k,v in my_filter.items()
        ]
s = pd.DataFrame(series, columns=series[0].index).T.any(axis=1)
ix = s[s==True].index
df.loc[ix]
```

This seems to do the job...
But I'm not sure this is memory efficient and (IMHO) this is neither straightforward nor easy to understand.

Is there a way in pandas to make some kind of serialisation of the "|" or "&" operators ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us try

```
out = df[np.any([df[k].isin(v) for k,v in my_filter.items()], axis=0)]
```

Comment: Thanks ! I had totally forgotten any/all exist in numpy...